# Splitting a tab delimited table into chunks of columns using BASH

Tags: bash, unix, split

Lets say I have a 100 line tab delimited file with 100 values in each line. Is there any way to split the file in such a fashion that I can get five 100 line files with 20 values in each line, essentially splitting 100 columns into chunks of 20 columns. This solution should be scalable to about 60k columns with 60 chunks (1000 columns).

I tried using split, but I quickly realized that is only for splitting along lines rather than columns.

Comment: Please show some sample input and output (say, 12 columns of input and 3 columns of output)  so that everyone is clear on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is what `cut` does.

```bash
cut -f 1-20 < file > subfile1
cut -f 21-40 < file > subfile2
...
```

Looping through chunks

```bash
chunksize=1000
ncol
for ((col=1; col <= ncol ; col = col+chunksize))
do
   cut -f $col-$((col+chunksize-1)) < file > subfile_$col
done
```

Comment: Right but is there a way to do this without writing out a line for each individual chunk.